# PHP: How to create seperate ARRAY() in the main ARRAY() depending on IF/ELSE STATEMENT?

Tags: php, arrays

Good Day Guys, I have a problem in **array()** in php. I have a **(2) $_POST Arrays** below **$continents** and **$countrie**s. I used **array_combined** to execute using **IF/ELSE STATEMENT** when the system find either **('asia','europe','america')** then I want to create new **array()** for each continents and I can't use **array_slice()** because the array values depend on the user selections. Is this Correct? Example Below.

```
$continents = array('europe','europe', 'asia', 'asia','america','america');
$countries = array('england','spain', 'iraq', 'china','chile','argentina');

$result = array_combine($countries,$continents);

// It this correct?       
if($result == 'asia'){

 // this is I want to execute. To create a new array   
 print_r( array('iraq','china') ); 

}else if($result == 'europe'){

  // this is I want to execute.To create a new array   
  print_r( array('england','spain') ); 

}else if($result == 'america'){

  // this is I want to execute. To create a new array  
  print_r( array('chile','argentina') ); 

}
```

**Thanks Guys!**

Comment: combine will return an array whose keys are continents and values are countries.. so the `if/else` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a loop:

```
$continents = array('europe', 'europe', 'asia', 'asia', 'america', 'america');
$countries = array('england', 'spain', 'iraq', 'china', 'chile', 'argentina');

echo '<br/>Original Array:<pre>';
print_r(array_combine($countries, $continents));
$cochinada = array_combine($countries, $continents);
echo '</pre><br />';

foreach($cochinada as $key => $value){
    $array2[$value][] = $key;
}

echo '<br/>Final Array:<pre>';
print_r($array2);
echo '</pre>'
```

And the output is:

```
Original Array:
Array(
[england] => europe
[spain] => europe
[iraq] => asia
[china] => asia
[chile] => america
[argentina] => america
)

Final Array:
Array(
[europe] => Array(
        [0] => england
        [1] => spain
    )
[asia] => Array(
        [0] => iraq
        [1] => china
    )
[america] => Array(
        [0] => chile
        [1] => argentina
    )
)
```

Comment: Wow. Worked like a charm!! This is what I looking for! Thank You Very Much. I alread used foreach but I dont know how to seperated them by a new a new sets of arrays. I thought I will need If/else for this. BTW Thanks @Solrac Ragnarockradio

Comment: Anytime man, just don't forget to mark this answer as the right one if it solved your problem :)

Comment: It is possible that It could make a new variable for these new arrays? example the continent america it would be a ex. $america = array('chile','argentina'); to use outside of the foreach?

Comment: You can use it outside of the foreach as it is...

The array you are searching for is `$array2['america']` this contains `array('chile', 'argentina')` and you can call it from anywere outside of the foreach.

Comment: oh nc. Thank You very much brother. I appreciated it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Solrac Ragnarockradio , I have one more problem. I will add another array, which is the abbreviation of the countries. `Ex: $abbrv = array('eng','spn','irq','chn','chl','arg');`. And One more problem is the `array_combine` bec. it exceeds 2 parameters only? It is possible to combine these 3 arrays $continents,$countries,$abbrv

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
$continents = array(
    '0' => 'europe', 
    '1' => 'europe', 
    '2' => 'asia', 
    '3' => 'asia', 
    '4' => 'america', 
    '5' => 'america'
    );

$countries = array(
    '0' => 'england', 
    '1' => 'spain', 
    '2' => 'iraq', 
    '3' => 'china', 
    '4' => 'chile', 
    '5' => 'argentina'
    );

$result = array_combine($countries,$continents);


print_r($result);

// It this correct?       
if($result == 'asia'){

    $new_cont[] = array(
        '0' =>  'iraq',
        '1' =>  'china'
        );

 // this is I want to execute. To create a new array   
    print_r($new_cont); 

}else if($result == 'europe'){

    $new_cont[] = array(
        '0' =>  'england',
        '1' =>  'spain'
        );

 // this is I want to execute. To create a new array   
    print_r($new_cont); 

}else if($result == 'america'){

    $new_cont[] = array(
        '0' =>  'chile',
        '1' =>  'argentina'
        );

 // this is I want to execute. To create a new array   
    print_r($new_cont);

}
```

Read this

1. [`array_combine()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_combine.asp)
2. [`array_merge()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp)
3. [`array_diff()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp)

Comment: I am not sure.. but can we compare an array with a simple string literal.. I mean it will be erroneous, won't it?.

Comment: @minato Hi, Thanks for this, But i need i a new sets of arrays.